# How to add interface for object of objects

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create an interface for my object. Below is the Data structure of object:

```
{
 "isLoaded": true,
 "items": {
         "0": {
            "name": "Mark",
            "age": "40"
        },
        "1": {
            "name": "Alex",
            "age": "41"
        },
        "2": {
            "name": "Foo",
            "age": "42"
        },
    }
}
```

The interface I have created looks like this

```
interface Items {
 "name": string;
 "age": string;
}
```

```
interface ItemData {
 "isLoaded": boolean;
 "items" : Items;
}
```

Is this the right way to create an interface for above data structure?

Answer (score 3):

```
interface ItemData {
  "isLoaded": boolean;
  "items" : {
     [key: string]: Items
   }
}
```

**ref** https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types

Comment: thanks. Can you please explain the above!!
or can you provide any references to understand?

Comment: @karan92 https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types

Answer (score 1):

```
interface Item {
   name: string;
   age: string;
}
```

```
  interface ItemData {
     isLoaded: boolean;
     items: {
       [key: string]: Item
     }
  }
```

Or the same thing but a little cleaner

```
interface ItemData {
  isLoaded: boolean;
  items: Record<string, Item>
}
```

You wrote

```
interface ItemData {
 "isLoaded": boolean;
 "items" : Items;
}
```

which means `items` is a singe `Items` object, while it should be a record of `Items` objects stored by string keys.

`[key: string]:  Item` is an [indexable type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types) and `Record<string, Item>` is a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) which the same indexable type under the  hood